# why I cannot allocate memory for an array within a function?

Tags: c++

I remember that I can pass a pointer to a function to allocate memory for it. The allocated memory will exist until I use delete[] to free it. When I wrote this toy code, I found access error:

```
 "Exception thrown: read access violation. x1 was 0x1110112."
```

I got confused by this error, I did it before without any exception. Could you tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>


void alloc_mem(float *x, int nx)
{
    x = new float[nx];
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
}


int main()
{
    float *x1 = nullptr;
    int nx = 10;
    alloc_mem(x1, nx);

    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    {
        std::cout << x1[i] << std::endl; //exception throw here
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointers allow you to pass an object by reference, but the pointer itself is passed by value. If you want to change the value of the pointer inside a function, the pointer must also be passed by reference. Rystyx is right though. In this case just return the sucker.

Comment: `x1` is null for the entire lifetime of your program.  You initialize it to `nullptr` and nowhere in your program is the value of `x1` changed.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way to return something from a function

```
#include <iostream>


float *alloc_mem(int nx)
{
    float *x = new float[nx];
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    int nx = 10;
    float *x1 = alloc_mem(nx);
    ...
}
```

If you want a function to return a value (such as a pointer to some allocated memory) then the simplest way to to use `return`.

Your version assigned the allocated memory to the variable `x` in `alloc_mem` but that variable is not the same variable as `x1` in `main`. That variable does not change.

Comment: `return new float[nx]();` is sufficient to allocate and zero-fill. Which kinda makes the function a bit pointless.

Comment: And don't do that. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: I am working on a big project. I wrote a small allocation function to allocate some arrays in one time. But I found this problem. So I did a demo code for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you change:

```
void alloc_mem(float *x, int nx)
```

to

```
void alloc_mem(float *& x, int nx)
```

(that is, make `x` a reference), then this function will work. Right now, the code you have passes an uninitialized pointer to the function, that function allocates memory, but `main()` never sees that. In your posted code, the pointer variable in `main()` is not the same pointer object as in `alloc_mem()`.

Comment: AH!! I see! You mean even I pass the pointer to a function, actually I pass the value of the address (the function creates a copy of address), so the function can access the value of that address and change it. But when it allocate memory for that, it allocate memory for the copy rather than the original one. Is that correct?

Comment: @YS_Jin Very close to correct. You do not allocate memory *for* the pointer, that was done automatically when the pointer is created. What you're doing is allocating an object in dynamic storage and pointing at it. The pointer is not the memory; it's a variable telling you where to find the memory.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This answer really solved my blind point! Although I studies C++ for months, but I did not truly understand the mechanism of pointer!

Comment: It should be noted that this is _not_ the idiomatic approach for a function that allocates memory, either in C or C++. See the other answer by john for a more "normal" approach where the pointer is the return value. Note also that the loop is unnecessary. You can zero-initialize when allocating memory as follows: `new float [nx]();`

Comment: I am working on a big project. I wrote a small allocation function to allocate some arrays in one time. But I found this problem. So I did a demo code for this question.